# CSS word wrap / line break on underscores in addition to whitespace and hyphens

Tags: css, word-wrap, line-breaks

I have a bunch of really long file names that cause my HTML formatting to overflow.  All of these filenames use underscores instead of spaces and would break/wrap easily if they were spaces.  Like this.

Here_is_an_example_of_a_really_long_filename_that_uses_underscores_instead_of_spaces.pdf

Is there some way to tell CSS to treat underscores in text as if they were whitespace or hyphens, and thus wrap/break on underscores too?  Like this.

Here_is_an_example_of_a_really_long_
file_name_that_uses_underscores_
instead_of_spaces.pdf

For my purposes, I cannot use a script to do this.  I also don't want to use the word-wrap:break-word trick because that usually doesn't work without also specifying a width.  Also, it breaks arbitrarily in the middle of words.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

You can use the [`<wbr>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) ("Line Break Opportunity element"), which lets the browser break the line wherever you place it.

So your HTML should be:

```html
Here_<wbr>is_<wbr>an_<wbr>example_<wbr>of_<wbr>a_<wbr>really_<wbr>...
```

You can add this tag on the server-side before you output the HTML.

An alternative is the entity [`&#8203;`](https://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) which is a zero width space. Sometimes this works better on certain browsers.

Comment: Note that this is a new HTML5 tag, might not be 100% supported in all browsers

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately, I can't do any server-side processing of the filenames.  I need some way to tell the browser to treat underscores as if they were spaces or hyphens.  I was hoping there was some CSS jujitsu I could pull that would allow me to do this.  Sort of like <span style="white-space-char:_">Here_is_an_example_of_a_really_long_filename_that_uses_underscores_instead_of_spaces.pdf</span>

Comment: It's not supported by IE8.

Comment: You've left fairly tight constraints to get the desired output. Without further scripts, or the acceptance of mid-word breaks, this simply isn't possible with just CSS.

Answer (score 28):

Use CSS

`word-break: break-all`

[jsfiddle - code](http://jsfiddle.net/99vHV/), 
[result](http://jsfiddle.net/99vHV/embedded/result/)

Comment: This will wrap on characters that are not underscores, as well.

Comment: This does not solve the Issue as this will wrap after each character and not only underscore.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you can't use CSS for this purpose currently.

But you can use JavaScript to add `<wbr>` tags automatically, for example:

```js
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('filename');
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i].innerHTML = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/_/g, '_<wbr/>');
}
```

```css
body { width: 250px; }
```

```html
<a class="filename">Here_is_an_example_of_a_really_long_filename_that_uses_underscores_instead_of_spaces.pdf</a>
```

Comment: <wbr> is valid for HTML5 i need to support IE 8 and above. Hence this solution does not help me. Thanks though .

Comment: @user, that is [fixable for IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756932/wbr-tag-doesnt-work-in-ie), but be sure to add that fix only to IE specific CSS (via conditional comments) as there are reports that zero-width spaces may become full spaces when copying in some cases. But there is no other way to do this in IE as far as I know.

Comment: That helped me. Thanks.
For `jQuery` =>`var fileName = $('.filename').html();`
`$('.filename').html(fileName.replace(/_/g, '_<wbr/>'));`

Answer (score 3):

Without using JavaScript nor `<wbr>` you could insert `<span> </span>` (notice the **space**) with following CSS:

```
span{
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The markup:

```
Here_<span> </span>is_<span> </span>an_<span> </span>example...
```

Answer (score 3):

Without HTML5, you can use Javascript to insert `<span></span>` before or after the characters you want to break on:

```
//Jquery
$("#id_of_the_container").html(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(/_/g, "_<span />");
});

//Pure Javascript
var htmlText = document.getElementById("id_of_the_container").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("id_of_the_container").innerHTML = htmlText.replace(/_/g, "_<span />");
```

then use the CSS class of the container to wrap the words :

```
.yourClass {
    word-break : break-word;
}
```

and finally set a zero pixel wide white space as the content before the span :

```
.yourClass > span:before {
    content: "\200b";
}
```

```js
$("#set").html(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace(/_/g, "_<span />");
});
```

```css
.boxes-container > div {
  margin: 5px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border : solid black 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding : 5px;
}

.bigger {
  margin-right : 200px !important;
}

.wrap {
  word-break: break-word;
}

.wrap > span:before {
  content : "\200b";
}

.answer-example {
  color : RGB(0, 50, 0);
  border-color: RGB(0, 50, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="boxes-container">
  <div class="bigger">
    Without_Anything,
    Long_Strings_With_Underscores_Make_text_Hard_To_Wrap
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    Without_Span_tags,
    Long_Strings_With_Underscores_Make_text_Hard_To_Wrap
  </div>
  <div id="set" class="wrap answer-example">
    With_Span_tags,
    Long_Strings_With_Underscores_Make_text_Hard_To_Wrap
  </div>
</div>
```