# wbr tag doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Soft break  seems not to work in IE. Is there any alternative or how to make it work?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/88q54/1/

```
body {
font-size: 272px;    
}


<div>W<wbr/>o<wbr/>r<wbr/>d</div>
```

I want the "word" to be breakable when it doesn't fit window width. The work is wrapped in webkit and mozila, but doesn't in IE (10/11).

I know that for made words breakable I may use css word-break: break-all;

but I want to be able to put soft break in certain position of the word so css word-break doesn't work correctly for me.

Comment: css  wordwrap: break-word;

InterNet Explorer breaks word when the word exceeds the width at position where the character exceeds the limit. wbr cant be used for breaking words. its used inside of nobr blocks to break sentences but not words

Comment: As they always say – “<del>Don’t</del> be [shy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#Suggesting_line_break_opportunities)”

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add the following into your style sheet:

```
wbr:after { content: "\00200B"; }
```

This inserts U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE, which is the character-level counterpart of the good old `<wbr>` that browsers have largely spoiled (a [sad story](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#wbr)).

Alternatively, you can replace `<wbr>` tags by that character, which you can write in HTML as `&#x200b;`.

Comment: Added `&#x200b;` where word breaks are possible. In my case after underscores (`_`). Works perfect in IE11 and Chrome 42

Comment: wbr:after does not seem to work for IE11, because I believe <wbr> would be considered an empty tag. According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24702765/2499165 most browsers don't implement :after for empty tags.

Comment: Also works for truncated tooltips if you insert `\u200b` chars

Answer (score 4):

Jukka's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23759279/2450941) is a good one. However, in the case below, it's desireable to allow the user to copy the text, which is an e-mail address. In that scenario, the `&#x200b;` character can't sneak into the string. It therefore has to be solved differently, using multiple inline elements (e.g. `<span>` or `<i>`) with `display: inline-block;`.

In this instance, `<i>` tags surround e-mail address components ending with a `.` or starting with a `@`.

```
.wbr-i-container i {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: inherit;
}

<a class="wbr-i-container"
><i>FirstName.</i
><i>MiddleName.</i
><i>LastName</i
><i>@company.</i
><i>com</i
></a>
```

`<i>` is used for brevity & readability, while `<span>` would be semantically correct.

Works in current versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari.