# Can you wrap text on an @ symbol?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to wrap text just before or after the @ symbol in an email address? HTML or CSS, or perhaps js/jQuery are all possibilities for a solution.

I'm trying to tidy up an admin page of a website and reduce the width of some columns without losing visual data, and this is the prime candidate!

Comment: With HTML and CSS you can't specify where the break would occur, only that you can force it *to* break. So you'd need JavaScript to break it specifically at the `@`. But you haven't shown what you've tried in your question.

Comment: could you just replace"@" with "<br>@" ?

Comment: Unless I mis-understand you @j08691, this isn't entirely correct, as there is the [`<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) tag which will break if necessary (Edit: I've just noticed that it doesn't work in IE, sigh!)

Comment: @freefaller `<wbr>` has no IE support at all and would require it being inserted in the content.

Comment: @j08691 yes, I've just discovered that, which means my use of it recently is now invalid, and I need to go and re-evaluate that code :-(  In my defence, the OP does say *HTML... are all possibilities*

Comment: Ah, but according [to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23759279/930393) using `&#x200b;` will work, even on IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an inline `span` tag on a character.

```
$("p").html($("p").text().replace('@', '<span class="after">@</span>'));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/21jqbtv9/5/

If you'd like what's before or after a particular character, you should use `lookahead` and `lookbehinds` respectively.

`lookbehind`: /(?<=@).+/

`lookahead`: /.+(?=@)/

Change the first argument of the `replace()` function to one of the above regex. Here is another example with a fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var email = $("p").html();
    var emailParts = email.split('@');
    var beforeText = emailParts[0];
    var afterText = emailParts[2];
   $("p").html($("p").html().replace(beforeText, "<span class='after'>" + beforeText + "</span>"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jL5kL72q/

For the part after the `@` symbol, just change `beforeText` to `afterText`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the HTML encoded `&#x200b;`

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23759279/930393) it will produce the same result as the [`<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) tag that I **was** going to suggest (until j08691 pointed out doesn't work in IE).

So you could have the email address as something like...

```
email&#x200b;@example.com
```

Here is an example of the character in action that you can run through the snippet...

```html
<div>
quickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogquickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog&#x200b;quickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogquickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
</div>
```